# BizTalk and SalesForce integration: the query or retrieve function returns unknown type

Tags: soap-api, wsdl2apex, query-editor

The bit  "sf:**Contact" is causing the issue.
BizTalk will try to ensure the message is “well formed”, but it is not as ‘sf’ is an undeclared prefix.

Comment: Can you add some more context to how your implementation works? What approach are you following? Which WSDL are you using? Where does BizTalk look for the definition of the sf prefix?

Comment: I'm trying to use Enterprise WSDL from salesforce in the Biz talk Service Bus Service and I'm querying Salesforce "Select FirstName, LastName from Contact". The ‘queryResponse’ message it returned was: <records xsi:type="sf:Contact" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><sf:Id xsi:nil="true" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" />  <sf:FirstName xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">Colin</sf:FirstName> </records>   The value 'sf:Contact' is invalid according to its schema type 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:QName' - 'sf' is an undeclared prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran the same query against the Enterprise API using SOAP UI.

## Request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:SessionHeader>
         <urn:sessionId>00D300000000001!AQ0AQPwsX1.NotARealSessionId.NNP_bYzscFelaPcv.NZrNEa1VncozL3.u7MQVbYmP5beuqSdqrlbcxJ5tbQ8cwPyS</urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:query>
         <urn:queryString>Select FirstName, LastName from Contact</urn:queryString>
      </urn:query>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

## Response

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com"
>
   <soapenv:Header>
      <LimitInfoHeader>
         <limitInfo>
            <current>344</current>
            <limit>15000</limit>
            <type>API REQUESTS</type>
         </limitInfo>
      </LimitInfoHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <queryResponse>
         <result>
            <done>true</done>
            <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"/>
            <records xsi:type="sf:Contact">
               <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
               <sf:FirstName>Colin</sf:FirstName>
               <sf:LastName>Ferretti</sf:LastName>
            </records>
            <size>1</size>
         </result>
      </queryResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

You can see in the response envelope that the `sf` namespace is defined.

Has something in Biz Talk manipulated the response to get just the records and lost the XML namespace definitions in the process?